# Right way to subtract in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following query in my stored procedure

```
DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @TenPercent int
DECLARE @RowsCount int

SET @TenPercent =10
SET @I = 1

SELECT 
    @I, dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeCode, dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeName
FROM 
    dbo.tblVegetationType 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink ON dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink.VegTypeID
INNER JOIN 
    tblCMAVegTypeLink ON dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID = dbo.tblCMAVegTypeLink.VegTypeID
WHERE   
    dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >= (@PercentCleared - @TenPercent)
    AND dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink.VegetationFormationID = @VegetationFormationID
    AND dbo.tblCMAVegTypeLink.CMAID = @CMAID
```

I have following condition

```
dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >= (@PercentCleared - @TenPercent)
```

What I am trying to do here: if `PercentCleared` is 60% then I want to query to pick the list from 50 %.

So I just add the `SET @TenPercent = 10` and subtract from the condition.

Is that a right way to do?

Comment: I don't see any declaration for `@PercentCleared`?

Comment: +Usher It's ok, you should see whether you're getting proper result and as Raj mention @PercentCleared variable is missing.

Comment: is this is performance related question?

Comment: sorry , i just partially posted my store proc. I do have declared @percentCleard in my store proc.

Comment: I just wondering how the performance will be affect doing like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing the query can be:

```
SELECT @I,
       VT.VegTypeCode,
       VT.VegTypeName
FROM dbo.tblVegetationType VT
INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink VTVF
ON VT.VegTypeID = VTVF.VegTypeID
INNER JOIN tblCMAVegTypeLink CVT
ON VT.VegTypeID = CVT.VegTypeID
WHERE 1= case when  @PercentCleared >= 60 and  VT.PercentageCleared <= 50 then 1
-- you can add condition when @PercentCleared < 60 then what values of   
-- VT.PercentageCleared are to be considered
        when  @PercentCleared < 60 and  VT.PercentageCleared <= 50 then 1
        end
AND VTVF.VegetationFormationID = @VegetationFormationID
AND CVT.CMAID = @CMAID
```